# Convert elements of a list from string to list

Tags: python

I've a `string represenation` of list `inside a list`.

`l=['[0, 1]', '[2, 3]']`

and I need to convert it into the list

`l=[[0, 1], [2, 3]]`

but I don't know how. Till now to change a string to a list I had used the split mehod but it seems not useful here. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: If your strings are only ever representations of lists of ints, then you could use the `json` module.

Comment: Do the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/how-to-convert-string-representation-of-list-to-a-list) help at all?

Comment: @quamrana OP *could* use the `json` module, but this runs the risk of conflating `json` with `ast`, which have two distinct purposes. `ast` is the better fit here, since they are trying to convert a string to a python object, rather than parse a json string

Comment: @C.Nivs: Yes, I'm sure that `ast` can be used. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with that module and its not 100% clear where this data came from, so `json` *could* be useful.

Comment: This question differnt..I request to open this question again...Applying `eval` directly or `json.load` deosn't solve the problem

Comment: @Bhargav: How is this question different? I'm quite happy with the selected duplicate.

Comment: @quamrana  Have you applied `eval` or `Json.load()` on this exaple? have you got outputs? it's not string representaion of list...it's string represenation of list inside a list

Comment: @Bhargav: This question is not that different. The answers in the duplicate use `ast` and `json`. Its easy to apply the same techniques to this question. One solution could be: `l = [json.loads(item) for item in l]`

Comment: Yeah atlast we have to apply `ast` and ` json` before that we need to modify the input by converting entire list to string so that it will become string represenation of `sublist` then we have to apply `ast` or `json`. I hope OP looking for way to achieve this process.

Comment: ohh @quamrana it was a nice solution!!!!..But if we use ast it wont be possible directly I guess